# Java Interface to load objects

Tags: java, interface

I need to load objects from a file. I don't know how to design the interface of classes that support this operation.

```
public interface TestComponent {
    TestComponent loadFromXML(Element _xmlElement); 
}
```

I can't make the method loadFromXML static, and I can't declare (not define!) a constructor - 
but it's pretty ugly to create a Class with the single purpose to call loadFromXML. It is also ugly to separate those mechanics within a utility class that calls a specified constructor within a switch-case.

How do you design an interface in that case? Should I maybe use abstract classes?

Comment: Why cant you declare a constructor nor make the method static? Are those requirements or you dont know how to?

Comment: because it's an interface - and you can't do that within an interface?

Comment: `loadFromXML static` Why not? Make your implementing class and create a new instance of whatever it is to send off as your `TestComponent`.

**EDIT**: Oh, interfaces can't have static classes in Java. Huh.

Comment: @Schifty, ya I got that, so it has to be an interface and not a normal class then?

Comment: TestComponent is extended by different interfaces and which are used by 10 different classes

Comment: Take a look at the Builder Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the version in your question looks a bit unnatural.

Here are some alternatives:

1. You could add a `void load(...)` to the `TestComponent` interface that will load "this" object with state from the XML.  (This is analogous to the `load` and `loadXML` methods on `java.util.Properties`.)
2. You could define a constructor in each `TestComponent` implementation classes that parses the XML to get the initial state of the object.
3. You could create a static helper method.
4. You could create a `TestComponentFactory` interface that has a `TestComponent load(...)` method that returns a loaded object.

The different approached have advantages and disadvantages.  For instance, the factory object approach (4.) separates the parsing / loading logic from the `TestComponent` class, but requires an extra class and interface.  On the other hand the other three approaches tend to be cumbersome if you have multiple implementations of the main interface.  The main problem is that you con't do polymorphism with constructors in Java.

Finally, if I was designing this, I'd make the `load(...)` method take a stream or reader as argument, and do the XML parsing itself (by calling the relevant library code).  That way you can take care of all of that in one place (per `TestComponent` implementation class).

Comment: would you mind to explain your first solution in detail - I'm not sure if I understood you

Comment: I added an example.  The first solution is the same as Michael's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Schifty one approach would be to change the return value of `loadFromXML` to `void`.  Instead of returning a new instance of `TestComponent`, this method would update the internal contents of the current object with the data from the XML document.

**Tip:** The access modifiers for interface methods are optional.  This is because interface methods must ALWAYS be defined as `public`.

```
public interface TestComponent {
    Element saveAsXML() throws ParserConfigurationException;
    TestComponent loadFromXML(Element _xmlElement);  
}
```

Comment: I do not like this solution - it's looks weird to me. Is there not a clean way to solve my problem without separating loadFromXML from TestComponent

Comment: Schifty you are not separating it, you are modifying the current object instead of returning a new object.

Comment: sorry - my comment was confusing - I understood your comment^^ - your answer looks like a workaround and not like a clean solution

Comment: @Schifty It is clean- loadingFromXML is an operation to prepare data for an object, and where better to include it than within the object? You can even call it in the constructor. Unless you have the need to load *without* caring about the data...